# Identity Server 3 Asp.Net Identity Sampe: Refresh Tokens

Tags: asp.net, authentication, token, asp.net-identity-2, identityserver3

I am using the Identity Server 3 Sample for Asp.Net Identity, which is working fine and I was also able to make it generate refresh tokens to renew the access tokens.

So here is my question. One of the main points of having refresh tokens is that we can simulate token revocation, in a way that we store the refresh token in a database table, then every time the user wants to renew the access token using that refresh token, we first check if that refresh token exists in the database then let it renew the access token. So if we remove that DB record, the user won't be able to renew his token, hence token revoked.

Now in Identity Server 3, I can simply activate the refresh tokens for a client by adding `UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true` to that client. But how do I store them in the DB and how do I make the token renewal process check the existence of that refresh token before accepting it?

Is there a better way to do this? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: If you are using Asp.net Identity then Token would be stored with claims which is handled by Asp.net User Manager service as User store. So if you mark the property `UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh` to true. It will automatically update the token when the refresh would be requested. To check the token you can use xx.xx.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value. This actually finds the claims and you would only use it for logout purpose. Everything is handled internally in ID3 and Asp.net Identity. Not sure you need to provide custom handling for token refreshing.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am very much beginner when it comes to Identity Server, so I need more basic go through! Just wondering, are you interested in one or a few paid sessions of Q&A where I can ask my questions and you answer them? (if you are professional in using Identity Server 3)